# How to count number of comparison in Mergesort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

The average number of comparisons performed by merge sort algorithm in merging two sorted list of length 2 is ?

Give your answer with explanation....

Comment: What input set are we averaging over?

Comment: @SandeepKumar was it useful?

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

N log N

N comparisons to merge N elements (two N/2 lists) - each comparison yields one element of the final answer. There are log N levels to the recursion, so the total number of comparisons is ~ N log N.

Edit: In each merge, we're left with a few elements in one list in the end, that we don't need to compare. So there will be a few less comparisons.

Comment: The lists in this problem have a fixed length, so the answer should be a constant.